# How come an empty numpy array after slicing have multi dimension and non zero?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

In python numpy, how can i understand the situation where an array becomes empty after slicing as below, but the shape is still multi dimensional and non zero too.

```
    import numpy as np

    x = np.matrix([[1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6],
                   [7,8,9]])
    y = x[0:2,3:5]

    print(y)            # []
    print(y.shape)      # (2, 0)
```

Comment: `np.matrix` operations return another `np.matrix`, which by definition is 2d.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment I blamed it on `np.matrix`, but it's actually a slicing issue:

```
In [57]: np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)[0:2, 3:5]                                                              
Out[57]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=int64)
In [58]: np.matrix(np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3))[0:2, 3:5]                                                   
Out[58]: matrix([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=int64)
```

Python allows us to slice lists outside of the 'range', and `numpy` does as well.  `3:5` is outside of the column dimension, so produces a 0 dimension.

A multidimensional array can have a 0 dimension.  The total number of elements is the product of the dimensions, in this case 0.

Other ways of making such an array:

```
In [61]: np.array([[],[]])                                                                                   
Out[61]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
In [62]: np.zeros((2,0))                                                                                     
Out[62]: array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```